# Feed info from litems in ListView in SplitView

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm attempting to build a SplitView with a ListView similar to the SplitView example available in the [XAML Controll Gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk3nv.png).

I have a list of objects, the names of which are displayed in the ListView on the left. What I can't figure out is

1. How to design the _ItemClick function in my .xaml.cs-file to pass the selected object to the content display on the right.
2. Exactly what to put in the second grid row. Currently is just text blocks, but since they have no ItemsSource, I assume you can't pass data to them like you can with the ListView.

Code outline:

```
    <SplitView Name="..."
               ...
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="SYSTEM"
                           x:Name="SystemHeader"
                           Margin="60,12,0,0"
                           Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                <ListView Grid.RowSpan="1" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Margin="0,12,0,0"
                          SelectionMode="None"
                          Name="MyListView"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource WLY_DefaultItemTemplate}"
                          ItemsSource="{x:Bind WLYs}"
                          ItemClick="WLYListView_ItemClick"
                          IsItemClickEnabled="True"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Grid.Row="2"
                            Margin="14,24,0,24">
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="LAYOUT DETAILS" Margin="12,12,0,0" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="content" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,12,0,0" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" />
        </Grid>
    </SplitView>
```

Could anyone outline how to achieve this, or point me to a resource that does?

EDIT: I think i figured out the _ItemClicked function:

```
private void WLYListView_ItemClicked(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var clickedItem = e.ClickedItem;
    selectedWLY = (WLY)clickedItem;
}
```

Comment: Cant you just synchronize the listview current item with the itemssource and then bind the details view to `WLYs/`?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but I'm not sure how. Currently, I have an event handler listening for clicks on items in the listview, and taking that to another object. However, I can't seem to figure out what kind of structure to use in the details view in order to display the data.

Comment: Maybe try to see how this example does it https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2017/02/06/building-splitview-navigation-in-uwp/

Comment: @Liam when I say "synchronize the listview current item with the itemssource" I really mean [IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_Selector_IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem) and when I say "bind the details view to `WLYs/`" I literally mean `<Grid DataContext="{x:Bind WLYs/}">` or something similar. Is that what you tried to do?